# How to delete top 5 oldest lines out of multiple text files (*.txt) in one folder?

Tags: powershell, text-processing

I'm looking for the way how to delete top 5 oldest lines out of multiple text files (*.txt) in one folder using powershell. Each text file is comma-delimited and every line starts with date "mm/dd/yyyy" (except Header)

This code will delete all lines older than '01/01/2014' but I need to delete top 5 oldest lines (records are sorted from oldest to newest), so I need to delete lines from 2 to 6 (first row of each file is a Header and I want to keep it). Any idea?

```
foreach ($file in gci *.txt){
   (gc $file) |
     ? {[datetime]$_.split(',')[0] -ge '01/01/2014'
     } | set-content $file
```

I also find this webpage http://powershell-tips.blogspot.ca/2011/05/display-top-n-lines-or-last-1n-lines-of.html may be based on this webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-skip` from `Select-Object`

```
foreach ($file in gci *.txt){
   (gc $file) |
     ? {[datetime]$_.split(',')[0] -ge '01/01/2014'
     } | Select-Object -skip 5 | set-content $file
```

Comment: Sorry, the code is not working and the SKIP command would skip first 5 lines and I need to delete lines from 2 to 6 (first line of each file is a header and i need to keep it). Thank you for trying.